# Get users full name from their Facebook link

Tags: c#, facebook, api, graph

I've been looking around for a way to get someone's full name (as displayed on their facebook account) by following a link.

For instance, if you were to type https://www.facebook.com/zuck in your browser, everyone would be able to see that his name is Mark Zuckerberg. I want to get this information from a C# application, based on a direct URL.

As far as I've understood by reading around, scraping is not allowed on facebook, so that's not an option. Another thing I've looked into is Facebooks Graph API, however it seems that it's not possible to get someone elses name using that api, you can only get your own name using your own access token. I can't really seem to understand whether or not this is possible/legal to even do this. Does anyone have any insight on this?

Comment: You can only get their name if they login to your app and grant your app permission to access it

Comment: Facebook has removed the username property (the `zuck` in your example) from the API a while ago, specifically to prevent stuff like what you are asking for.